# Unable to @Valid parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am using spring MVC 4 and tomcat 7.

I am new in java and have a validation issue (probably binding) for the `emailTo` parameter which I would like to be validated (in the UI).
I already spend my and other programmers time but with no success.

BindingResult result is empty for for emailTo but it fails throw exception when it trying to add it to the DB (due to the @NotNull annotation).
Means, the annotation works fine but the validation not...

The strange thing is that the validation works fine for `modifiedSince` parameter (@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)) but not for `emailTo`.

Oracle's table class via hibernate (Task.java under DBLayer project):

```
    package entities;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import enums.TaskIdentifierType;
import enums.TaskPriority;
import enums.TaskStatus;
import enums.TaskType;

@Entity
@Table(name="TASK", indexes= {@Index(columnList="TITLE"),
                              @Index(columnList="TYPE"),
                              @Index(columnList="STATUS")})
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "taskIdGen", sequenceName = "TaskSequence")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="TASK_ID")
    private int taskId;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String taskTitle;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="TYPE")
    private TaskType type;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private TaskStatus status;
    .
    .
    .   
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_SINCE")
    private Date modifiedSince;
    .
    .
    .
    @Column(name="VALID_PHRASE")
    private String validPhrase;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="EMAIL_TO")
    private String emailTo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="PRIORITY")
    TaskPriority priority;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=ResultItem.class, mappedBy="task", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Collection<ResultItem> resultItems;

    public Task() throws ParseException{
        timestamp = new Date();
        status = TaskStatus.NEW;
        priority = TaskPriority.NORMAL;
        resultItems = new ArrayList<ResultItem>();  
        identifierType = TaskIdentifierType.TS_ID;
        type = TaskType.DB;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

TaskController.java under LinkCheckerGUI project:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "task/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processCreationForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("taskModel")NewTaskModel taskModel, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        System.out.println("---------in task controller");

        if (taskModel == null){
            System.out.println("Task is null");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("------------task email to=" + taskModel.getTask().getEmailTo().toString());
        }

        System.out.println("--------------all Errors:" + result.getFieldErrors());

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for(ObjectError oe : result.getAllErrors()){
                System.out.println("-----------------error:"+oe.toString());    
    }
            System.out.println("-------Error found in new task values");/////////////////
            return "task/newTask";
        } 

        try {

            taskManager.addTask(taskModel.getTask());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        return "redirect:new";
    }
```

newTask.jsp under LinkCheckerGUI project:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta 

http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
    <title>LinkChecker</title>
    </head>
    <%-- <jsp:include page="headersMenu.jsp"/> --%>
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/staticFiles.jsp"/>
    <body>
    <h2><fmt:message key="task.add.title"/></h2>
    <div class="container">
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
    <form:form modelAttribute="taskModel" method="POST">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="task.taskTitle"/>Task name:</td>  
                <td><form:input path="task.taskTitle"/></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="task.invalidPhrase"/>Invalid Phrase:</td>  
                <td><form:input path="task.invalidPhrase"/></td>
            </tr>
        .
        .
        . 
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="task.validPhrase"/>Valid Phrase:</td>  
                <td><form:input path="task.validPhrase"/></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="task.modifiedSince" class="validationError"/>Modified Since:</td>  
                <td><form:input path="task.modifiedSince"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="task.modifiedSince" cssClass="validationError"/></td>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><form:label path="task.emailTo"/>Email To:</td>  
                <td class="validationError"><form:label path="task.emailTo"/>Email To:</td>  
                <td><form:input path="task.emailTo"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="task.emailTo" cssClass="validationError"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the relevant code from my two related projects (DBLayer and LinkCheckerGUI).

In this case, after clicking on 'submit':

1. > In the form, I get the requested validation message for the "Modified Since" field (I left it empty were it's definition is @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) ).
2. output:

> all Errors:[Field error in object 'taskModel' on field 'task.modifiedSince': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.taskModel.task.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.task.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [taskModel.task.modifiedSince,task.modifiedSince]; arguments []; default message [task.modifiedSince]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'task.modifiedSince'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Temporal @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date for value ''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]]
>   -----------------error:Field error in object 'taskModel' on field 'task.modifiedSince': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.taskModel.task.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.task.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.modifiedSince,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [taskModel.task.modifiedSince,task.modifiedSince]; arguments []; default message [task.modifiedSince]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'task.modifiedSince'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Temporal @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date for value ''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
>   -------Error found in new task values

3. > No other validation failure, although emailTo should fail because I left it empty as well.

When adding the binding (in the taskController.java):

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    //This WebDataBinder set the Date parameters to null in case they are empty
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    // true passed to CustomDateEditor constructor means convert empty String to null
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

The validation message for `modifiedSince` disappeared as expected and no other message displayed and the output is:

> ------------task email to= --------------all Errors:[]

Means, results doesn't hold any error (for the emailTo parameter).

If I'll remove the try/catch from the controller (for addTask method) it will crush (throw exception) because the emailTo parameter is empty and it's unable to add it to the DB (as expected).

****I created a simple class and it works fine. Is there a reason why it doesn't work Entity class?**?**

I would appreciate your assist here...

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Have you configured custom validator as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring)?

Comment: Hi, I wish to use the global validator. it seems the same to my configuration but my configuration has "<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>" (without the "service="conversionService" it fail to start the tomcat with "spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar - Unknown module".

Comment: So, did you specify anywhere in Spring validators that emailTo slould be @NonNull?

Comment: Yes, In Task.java (below). in addition, I see that adding  <mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator" conversion-service="conversionService"/>" instead of "<mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="conversionService"/>" resolves with exception:"No bean named 'globalValidator' is defined".

Comment: The strange thing is that the validation works fine for `modifiedSince` parameter (@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)) but not for `emailTo`.

Comment: In Task.java you have specified it with Hibernate, which you mentioned to throw exception. You need a Spring validator to handle REST request. I guess emailTo is considered to be a nullable String by default.

Comment: I created a simple local class (not from external project or class which also create a table) and it works fine. Is there a reason why it doesn't work with the external class (which also creates a table creation)?

Comment: Note that Temporal is from type javax.persistence.Temporal

Comment: Another thing, Task.java is an @Entity class.